# update Kernel after failed upgrade because full /boot partition

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel

Today I tried to update my two Linux servers. on one it failed because /boot did not have enough space, which was easy to solve. But now I have different Kernels on this machines because apt update/upgrade does not try to install the newest anymore on the machine where it failed on the first try.

How can I force the update now?

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS where update worked:

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-127-generic
```

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS where update FAILED:

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-31-generic


$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  amd64-microcode intel-microcode iucode-tool
Verwenden Sie »sudo apt autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
```

How to get the latest kernel also on this machine?

```
$ sudo apt list --installed 'linux-image*'
Auflistung... Fertig
linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-31.50 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-31.50 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
```

Output from 'apt-cache plicy linux-image-generic

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy linux-image-generic
linux-image-generic:
  Installiert:           (keine)
  Installationskandidat: 4.4.0.127.133
  Versionstabelle:
     4.4.0.127.133 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     4.4.0.21.22 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You get only one kernel version on the failing machine which is not normal, APT keeps at least two versions while updating. So let me ask: Has this machine ever updated the Linux kernel? Haven’t you held any packages related to kernel? How exactly did you clean the boot partition? BTW you should prepend `LANG=C` if you are about to post the command output (e.g. `LANG=C sudo apt-get upgrade`), so the output gets printed in English. I personally can understand German but others may not.

Comment: There were more versions before, but because of no space on /boot i deleted some of them using this hint https://askubuntu.com/a/90219/592185

Comment: Please edit your question the include the complete output of `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic`. Let's see if you simply need to reinstall the metapackage (happens if apt is blocked for too long).

Comment: Output added. 4.4.0.127.133 is exactly the version that it tried to install at morning but broke because of full /boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is missing the [`linux-image-generic`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-image-generic) package and probably also [`linux-generic`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-generic) which depends on the former. You should reinstall it using the command:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

The packages `linux-image-generic` and `linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic` (the currently latest version) should be included automatically to be installed by APT.